# How to avoid NumberFormatException while using BufferedReader?

Tags: java, c, io, bufferedreader

I used BufferedReader to read data from the user, but it gives NumberFormat Exception prvovided I give the input in a certain way. Suppose in C, I write the code like this:

```
scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
```

and i try to give the input to the console like this :  **23 45**, it assigns values like this:

> x = 23, y = 45

How can I do something like this in java. I tried like this :

```
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line1 = br1.readLine();
String line2 = br2.readLine();
int x = Integer.parseInt(line1);
int y = Integer.parseInt(line2);
```

But this gives:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "23 45"   at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)    at AB.main(AB.java:23)

Comment: What you wrote is read as one line if I'm not mistaken.
Try giving it like:
23 (enter) 45
If you want to achieve this, you'd have to read one line with all the numbers you want and then split this string by spaces

Comment: @user3248186 its taking input only one time or asks for 2 times?

Comment: readLine reads until the end of the line. In this case it should ask you twice

Comment: @Greyshack: I know that it takes it as one line and that it works if I press enter, but I wanted it to work with spaces as that's how it's given on websites like hackerearth.

Comment: Yep I told you, you can read only one line and then split it using String's split() method and passing " " as an argument for splitting

Comment: @NigamPatro yes it's asking me twice, I even tried with one bufferedReader object using it to read twice, that didn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your purpose

```
int x, y;
String[] input;
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String str = br.readLine();
  input = str.split(" ");

  x = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
  y = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`readLine()` reads until there is a newline, usually meaning that the user pressed enter.

If you input 12 34, this is one line, a line that isn't formatted like an integer.

You can either read a single char at a time by using `read()` instead, split the line manually and parse the results, or preferably use the `Scanner` class instead. It has a more user-IO oriented api, exposing methods such as `nextInt()` or `next()` (returning the next "token" instead of the next char) and so on.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = in.nextInt();
int y = in.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

One InputStreamReader is enough:

```
   BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line1 = br1.readLine();
    String[] args = line1.split(" ");

    if (args.length != 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input is wrong");
    }

    int x = getIntFromInput(args[0]);
    int y = getIntFromInput(args[1]);
```

and as Jan pointed out you will need a convertion method:

```
public static int getIntFromInput(String inputString) {

    //sanity checks
    if (inputString == null || inputString.trim().length() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty or null string passed");
    }

    try {
        return new BigInteger(inputString, 10).intValueExact();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("input string is not a valid integer number: '%s'", inputString));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... it would *still* throw NumberFormatException for input like `1212312312312312312312313 123432432432432423432423432`

Comment: @Jan, not it won't ;)

Comment: Oh **yes** it does. Try it once.

Comment: @Jan, please review :)

Comment: Now it at least does not throw NumberFormatExceptions any more.. but IllegalArgumentExceptions instead. Not sure how much that helps :)

Comment: @Jan, another review please. I've removed the pattern validation to allow both negative and positive numbers

Comment: Looks more clean now. And don't mind my being picky about bad input - had too many classes delivered to me that did bad error handling if at all...

Comment: @Jan, absolutely valid feedback. Too often we do not think of **all** possible combinations the user might through into our code. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to pass both parameters on the same line, split the line on the white spaces, then use each token separately :

```
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String line1 = br1.readLine();

String[] tokens = line1.split("\\s+") 

int x = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
int y = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Now here we are - many, many answers just explaining how to read *correct* input. But you'll get `NumberFormatExceptions` any other odd way. Like if your input would be...

```
98765432109876543210 9876543210987654321
```

This would in turn throw `NumberFormatException` as these are too large to fit into `int`.

So while splitting at `" "` and addressing tokens manually is good advice, you'd also run into `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` if for instance only *one* number was given.

My recommendation would be to check if the input **looks valid** before you do any further parsing:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = s.nextLine();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,10})\\s+(\\d{1,10})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if(m.matches()) {
  long x1 = Long.parseLong(m.group(1));
  long y1 = Long.parseLong(m.group(2));
  if(x1 <= Integer.MAX_VALUE&& y1 <= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {   
    int x = (int)x1;
    int y = (int)y1;
    System.out.printf("Your input: %d / %d", x, y);
  } else {
    System.err.println("Numbers too big");
  }
} else {
  System.err.println("Input does not match criteria");
}
```

Comment: how about negative numbers? :)

Comment: Right. No data in question wether these are valid or not. I'm an optimist here and will only see positive :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like that:

```
String in = *getline*;
String[] tab = in.split(' ');
List<int> nums = new         ArrayList<int>();

for(String a : tab){
nums.add(Integer.parseInt(a));         // or push() not remember...
}

// Your nums have your integers now
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read data from file and split string based upon 1 or more space and can handle multiple inputs separated by space.

```
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = s.nextLine();
        //String line = "98765432109876543210 9876543210987654321   ";
        String[] splited = line.split("\\s+");
```

Then compare each string to check whether it is valid number. 
Then create a new BigDecimal from that number. A BigDecimal on 64bit jvm with with memory permitting can hold upto 646456993 digits.

```
        for (int i=0;i<splited.length;i++) {

            if(splited[i].matches("[0-9]*")){

                BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(splited[i]);
                System.out.println("num "+(i+1)+"="+num);
            }
        }



 Results
 line ="98765432109876543210 9876543210987654321   "
 num 1=98765432109876543210
 num 2=9876543210987654321

 line ="1212312312312312312312313 123432432432432423432423432"
 num 1=1212312312312312312312313
 num 2=123432432432432423432423432
```